# pivot table data is not showing in blade php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have two tables orders and status. it related in a pivot table order_status

in my `Order` model

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withTimestamps();
}
```

in my `Status` model

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order')->withTimestamps();
}
```

in controller

```
$items = Order::orderBy('id','desc')->with('status')->paginate(20);

return view('dashboard.index', compact('items'));
```

now in blade.

```
@foreach($items as $key=>$row)
{{-- {{ dd($row->status()->orderBy('pivot_created_at','DESC')->first()->message ) }} --}} //it works if checked by dd()
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $row->status()->orderBy('pivot_created_at','DESC')->first()->message }}</span></td> //here it not works and says Trying to get property 'message' of non-object
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

kindly check my code. I repeat my problems once again. when I check output by dd() it returns clearly but when I want to show in blade it returns me Trying to get property 'message' of non-object. what can I do now? I did it in another project it worked for me but now it returns errors.

my php version: 7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dd() will display the very first row and then halt execution. The latter case will execute for every row. You are most likely encountering a row with no statuses at the second or later row.

`$row->status()->orderBy('pivot_created_at','DESC')->first()->message` is a fairly dense line of code with a number of things happening in it. To help understand exactly what is going wrong, you should look at breaking it into a few lines and add in some checks to handle this type of thing. A first run at that might look something like this:

```
$statuses = $row->status()->orderBy('pivot_created_at','DESC');
if ($statuses->count() > 0) {
   <td>{{ $statuses->first()->message }}</td>
}
```

That said, a cleaner long term solution might be to look into the `withDefault` functionality available to the relationship definition in the model, which is described on https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships